# Displaying subfiles and subfolders in datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, subdirectory

I have an XML file that contains a path to a bunch of folders and subfiles. I know how to read this file with LINQ. Now I want to learn how to show subfiles on DataGridView after selecting a folder on folderbrowserdialog. My DataGridView has 3 columns: file name, size and extension. Here is my code to read the path of bunch of folders on c#:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\XmlFolder.xml");
var query = from p in document.Descendants("Path")
                      select p;
string path = query.First().Value;
```

I am using visual studio and windows forms application. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Directory.GetFiles()` method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx). Pass the path of the selected folder from the `folderbrowserdialog` and loop through the string array so you can display them on the datagridview.